# error in a python class with an not iterable object

Tags: python, class, numpy, runtime-error

i have a the following error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2721, in run_code
    exec code_obj in self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns
  File "<ipython-input-257-84ae6ec7b6f6>", line 1, in <module>
    accuracy.ra_os
  File "<ipython-input-255-a91d95432efe>", line 32, in ra_os
    return np.average([(ref.intersection(s).area/s.area) for s in seg])
TypeError: 'Polygon' object is not iterable
```

where Polygon is the `Polygon class` of [shapely](http://toblerity.github.com/shapely/manual.html).

i have my own class Accuracy: stat values between reference (one) and segmented (one or more) polygons

```
ref = <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon at 0x4997b38>
seg = [<shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon at 0x4b972e8>, <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon at 0x49c7390>]



import math
import numpy as np
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
nan = np.nan



class Accuracy(object):
    def __init__(self, ref, seg=None):
        self.ref = ref
        self.seg = seg

    @property
    def area(self):
        return self.ref.area

    @property
    def perimeter(self):
        return self.ref.length

    @property
    def centroidX(self):
        return self.ref.centroid.x

    @property
    def centroidY(self):
        return self.ref.centroid.y

    @property
    def segments(self):
        if self.seg:
            return len(self.seg)
        else:
            return 0

    @property
    def ra_or(self):
        if self.seg:
            return np.average([(ref.intersection(s).area/ref.area) for s in seg])
        else:
            return nan

    @property
    def ra_os(self):
        if self.seg:
            return np.average([(ref.intersection(s).area/s.area) for s in seg])
        else:
            return nan
```

accuracy = Accuracy(ref, seg_overlap)
accuracy.ra_os

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2721, in run_code
    exec code_obj in self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns
  File "<ipython-input-45-84ae6ec7b6f6>", line 1, in <module>
    accuracy.ra_os
  File "<ipython-input-7-1e04291926b0>", line 35, in ra_os
    return np.average([(ref.intersection(s).area/s.area) for s in seg])
TypeError: 'Polygon' object is not iterable
```

if i run the function outside the class i have not this error

```
np.average([(ref.intersection(s).area/ref.area) for s in seg_overlap])
Out[47]: 0.48709794373000681
```

Comment: At some point you are setting `seg` to a single `Polygon` object.

Answer (score 3):

Did you mean to say `self.seg` instead of just `seg`:

```
return np.average([(ref.intersection(s).area/ref.area) for s in self.seg])
                                                                ^^^^^
```

(in both functions)

I think you're accidentally referring to the global object with the same name.

Comment: Thank NPE, it was my missing